# Extracting a linear equation from a graph

Tags: plotting, functions

```
xx = {1/273, 1/298, 1/308, 1/318, 1/328, 1/338};
yy = {-2.5421121235587796, 1.2412685890696329`, 2.6026896854443837`, 
   3.9080149840306073`, Log[150], Log[487]};
data = Transpose@{xx, yy};
ListPlot[data]
```

I have plotted a set of data. I'm trying to see if I can get the linear function that define this graph. 
I have attached the code for how I plotted the data and what the graph looks like.

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code as text, not as image, so people can easily copy / paste it in their MMA and play around. You will want to look into [`LinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearModelFit.html) to fit a line to your points.

Comment: Julissa use the { } button in the editor to include code in the post. It takes a bit getting use to but it helps people to see your code better and just copy and paste to see how to help you rather typing the whole thing again.

Comment: `I'm trying to see if I can get the linear function that define this graph` How about `Fit[data, {1,x},x]` which gives `42.7858 - 12375.8 x`